# Scraping relevant text passages from local text file

Tags: python, file, text, screen-scraping, local

I am looking for a piece of python code that is able to scrape relevant parts of texts. Lets say I have a set of words, and when it encounters one of the words, it scrapes 1 or 2 sentences after and ahead the sentence it found the word in. 
Then it should print the text below so it can be copied.

For example see the text below. Lets say the relevant word is 'simple'. It detects 'simple' in line 3. So it scrapes Line 2,3 and 4.

Beautiful is better than ugly. Explicit is better than implicit. Simple is better than complex. Complex is better than complicated. Readability counts.

Becomes ->

'Explicit is better than implicit. Simple is better than complex. Complex is better than complicated.'

I believe the idea for the code is simple. However I have no idea on how to achieve this.

```
import re

caps = "([A-Z])"
prefixes = "(Mr|St|Mrs|Ms|Dr)[.]"
suffixes = "(Inc|Ltd|Jr|Sr|Co)"
starters = "(Mr|Mrs|Ms|Dr|He\s|She\s|It\s|They\s|Their\s|Our\s|We\s|But\s|However\s|That\s|This\s|Wherever)"
acronyms = "([A-Z][.][A-Z][.](?:[A-Z][.])?)"
websites = "[.](com|net|org|io|gov)"

def split_into_sentences(text):
    text = " " + text + "  "
    text = text.replace("\n"," ")
    text = re.sub(prefixes,"\\1<prd>",text)
    text = re.sub(websites,"<prd>\\1",text)
    if "Ph.D" in text: text = text.replace("Ph.D.","Ph<prd>D<prd>")
    text = re.sub("\s" + caps + "[.] "," \\1<prd> ",text)
    text = re.sub(acronyms+" "+starters,"\\1<stop> \\2",text)
    text = re.sub(caps + "[.]" + caps + "[.]" + caps + "[.]","\\1<prd>\\2<prd>\\3<prd>",text)
    text = re.sub(caps + "[.]" + caps + "[.]","\\1<prd>\\2<prd>",text)
    text = re.sub(" "+suffixes+"[.] "+starters," \\1<stop> \\2",text)
    text = re.sub(" "+suffixes+"[.]"," \\1<prd>",text)
    text = re.sub(" " + caps + "[.]"," \\1<prd>",text)
    if "\"" in text: text = text.replace(".\"","\".")
    if "!" in text: text = text.replace("!\"","\"!")
    if "?" in text: text = text.replace("?\"","\"?")
    text = text.replace(".",".<stop>")
    text = text.replace("?","?<stop>")
    text = text.replace("!","!<stop>")
    text = text.replace("<prd>",".")
    sentences = text.split("<stop>")
    sentences = sentences[:-1]
    sentences = [s.strip() for s in sentences]
    return sentences

relevantwords = ["refugees","conflicts","mobility", "rights", "presence", "freedom", "immigrants", "politics", "political"] 


    for i in range(20):

    file = open("text"+str(i)+".txt", "r")
    data = file.readlines()

    for line in split_into_sentences(str(data)):
        if "relevantwords" in line:
            print str(i–1,i,i+1)
            print str(line).encode('UTF-8')
            print "\n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a rough outline of some code, and if you have trouble implementing it, feel free to post your code and I'll be happy to help you where you're having issues!

You'll want to:

1. Read the file into a string in a program
2. Split the string into sentences by splitting on the character `'.'`. Note that if you have abbreviations like "mr.", it will think that's the end of a sentence.
3. Iterate over the list of sentences now, and in each iteration, do:

   - Check if the word is in sentence `i`. If so, print out sentences `i-1`, `i`, and `i+1`
   - Or , if you don't want to print them out, you can add them to a list you create at the beginning

If you have any specific questions about how to implement this, let me know!

Comment: So I tried it to put some code together. But it is not working, plus I have no idea how to tackle your point 3. However, I tried though. But How can I paste the piece of code in the comments?

Comment: You can go to gist.github.com and paste your code there and then comment with the link and I'll be happy to take a look :)

Comment: Christopher, would you mind to review me. I am a super beginner in Python. :)